# Dlubal Rfem Seismic Analysis

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structural-analysis

I’m learning Dlubal Rfem recently and I have a problem about seismic analysis. When Equivalent Lateral Load is bigger than Modal base shear;for example on Sap2000 we scale modal base shear and we make equal(depends on code) modal base shear with Equivalent Load.I can’t find how to scale modal base shear on Rfem.can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the YouTube tutorials about this issue. I think this point was almost explained there.

An example link is:

- [Webinar: Seismic Equivalent Loads Using the Response Spectrum Analysis in RFEM (USA)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eyLIGwgjY98)

Comment: adding some links would be helpful